# ResponseError: Confluent_Schema_Registry - Error, status 400

Tags: node.js, registry, schema, avro, kafkajs

I'm using kafkajs and confluent-schema-registry in Nodejs. I can log the message.value (avro) but I'm having an error when trying to decode it. It says: ResponseError: Confluent_Schema_Registry - Error, status 400

```
const payload = await registry.decode(message.value).catch(error => {
      console.log('error consuming payload', error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your avro schema URL is on https, then try specifying Agent during initialzing SchemaRegistry.

```
const registry = new SchemaRegistry({
  host: 'Your host on https',
  // if you have auth for schema url
  auth: {
    username: 'username for schema url',
    password: 'password for schema url'
  },
  // specifying below agent explicitly helped us
  agent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
})
```